# How do I limit the results of a php query based on the value of a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Originally I had a `WHERE class_id = 3` in my php query but as I learned more about server-side things I realized I wouldn't be able to change that once the page was loaded without AJAX or something. So now I've taken away the `WHERE` part of my query and am getting results for all `class_id`'s.

My hope is that I can use a radio to limit the rows returned to only those matching the radio button that is checked.

EX. Click `class 2` radio button, click go, and now only rows with `class_id = 2` show up.

```
<input type='button' name='Go' value='Go' onclick='getSelected()'>

function getSelected() {
  var queryClass = "";
  if (classThree.checked) {
    queryClass = 3;
  } else if (classTwo.checked) {
    queryClass = 2;
  } else if (classOne.checked) {
    queryClass = 1;
  }
}
```

I can get the desired value with this but I don't know what to do with the value to limit the rows. If this is possible it'd be great to know how.

Comment: you will either need to send the `queryClass` value back to php via ajax to limit the query and return the resulting rows **or** when you build your result in php add a class or data-attribute with the `class_id`, and filter out the results with `.hide()` or other action.